# retrieving individual records through angularjs from mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have an api that fetches categories from my mongodb collection which is as follows:

```
app.get('/categories', function (req, res) {

Category.find(function (err, categories) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);

  res.json(categories);
  });
});
```

This is used to display a dropdown which contains a list of categories:

```
<a href="#/gallery">Our Designs &#9662;</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="" ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category.name}}</a></li>
      </ul>
```

I want to access a specific category via its "_id" i.e. /categories/:_id whenever a category link is clicked, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having problem with mongoose, your answer is below

```
app.get('/categories/:_id', function (req, res) {

    var categoryId = req.params._id; // GET THE CATEGORY ID FROM THE GET REQUEST

    var filter = {_id: categoryId} // CREATE YOUR FILTER AS YOU WISH

    Category.find(filter, function (err, categories) { //USE YOUR FILTER AS THE FIRST ARGUMENT OF THE FIND METHOD
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json(categories);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hira, can you vote my answer as the right one? so your questions will be closed and I get my points :D Thanks!